# Javascript regex error possibly needs look-back type functionality?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I'm trying to complete a exercise on a Javascript learning website.

The instructions were:

- Input: String of words, where some words may contain a hashtag/pound sign #.
- Output: Array of strings that were prefixed with the hashtag/pound sign #, but do not contain the hashtag/pound sign #.
- Pound signs alone do not count, for example: the string "#" would return an empty array.
- If a word is preceded by more than one hashtag, only the last hashtag counts (e.g. "##alot" would return ["alot"])
- Hashtags cannot be within the middle of a word (e.g. "in#line hashtag" returns an empty array)
- Hashtags must precede alphabetical characters (e.g. "#120398" or "#?" are invalid)

My effort was this:

```
function getHashtags(post) {
  return /#(\w+)/.exec(post)
}
```

but it's resulting in this:

```
String Input: Hello #world
Outpu t: [ '#world', 'world', index: 6, input: 'Hello #world' ]

String Input: #lol #sorryNotSorry #heya #coolbeans
Output: [ '#lol','lol', index: 0, input: '#lol #sorryNotSorry #heya #coolbeans']

String Input: # # # #
Output: null

String Input: this is an in#line hash
Output: [ '#line', 'line', index: 13, input: 'this is an in#line hash' ]

String Input: too ##many tags
Output: [ '#many', 'many', index: 5, input: 'too ##many tags' ]

String Input: invalid chars #$? #;wha
Output: null

String Input: "" //empty string
null

String Input: #blue#red#yellow#green
Output:[ '#blue', 'blue', index: 0, input: '#blue#red#yellow#green' ]
```

I think I need lookback functionality but I know Javascript doesn't support it and I haven't been able to find a workaround! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You're actually doing it (almost) correctly. When you use `exec` it only returns the first set of results. If you continue to call `exec` (assuming you're using the global flag `g`) it will begin to return the next matches. This example was taken from mozilla's site:

```
var myRe = /ab*/g;
var str = 'abbcdefabh';
var myArray;
while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) !== null) {
  var msg = 'Found ' + myArray[0] + '. ';
  msg += 'Next match starts at ' + myRe.lastIndex;
  console.log(msg);
}
```

[Exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

Might I add that everyone can learn from how well this question was asked. Nice job showing what you've done to solve the problem. I'll even show you how you would implement this.

```
function getHashtags(post)
{
    regex = /#(\w+)/g;
    arr = [];

    while((results = regex.exec(post)) !== null)
    {
        arr.push(results[1]);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: @stribizhev & iismathwizard thank you so much for your help, I've used a hybrid of both of your methods                                       `function getHashtags(post) {  regex = /\B#+([a-z]\w*)/gi; ///#(\w+)/g;   arr = [];                                                                                     while((results = regex.exec(post)) !== null) { arr.push(results[1]); } console.log(arr) return arr; }` and it passes most cases but is stuck on #blue#red#yellow#green where it matches ['blue'] –

Answer (score 2):

> Hashtags cannot be within the middle of a word (e.g. "in#line hashtag" returns an empty array)

-- Use non-word boundary `\B` that does not allow a word character to appear right before the `#`. Also, to exclude the match when the `#` is in the middle of the hashtag, add a word boundary that is not followed by `#`: `(?!#)\b`.

> Hashtags must precede alphabetical characters (e.g. "#120398" or "#?" are invalid)

-- Use a `[a-zA-Z]` right after the `#` and then you can use `\w`. Or `[a-z]` if you plan to add `/i` modifier.

So, use

```
/\B#+([a-z]\w*(?!#)\b)/gi
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aO1oE9/3)

This will cover basic Latin-script based hashtag extraction.

```js
function getHashtags(post) {
  var re = /\B#+([a-z]\w*(?!#)\b)/gi;
  arr = []; 
  while ((m = re.exec(post)) !== null) {
    arr.push(m[1]);
    document.write("Hashtag: " + m[0] + ", name: " + m[1] + "<br/>");
  }
  return arr;
}


var strs = ['##alot', 'Hello #world', '#lol #sorryNotSorry #heya #coolbeans', '# # # #', 'this is an in#line hash', 'too ##many tags', 'invalid chars #$? #;wha', '', '#blue#red#yellow#green'];
strs.forEach(function (str) {
  console.log(getHashtags(str));
});
```

Comment: updating the `lastIndex` is not necessary as calling `exec` will do it for you

Comment: Not always, sometimes, exec freezes when you remove this part of code.

Comment: have anything to back that claim up?

Comment: 'If a word is preceded by more than one hashtag, only the last hashtag counts (e.g. "##alot" would return ["alot"])'. So the regex should have `#+` instead of `#`, like this: `var re = /\B#+([a-z]\w*)/gi;`

Comment: @DavidKnipe I think it is a typo, *the last hash counts*.

Comment: I take that to mean that `##alot` should be treated the same as `#alot`. OP said it should return a nonempty array, but your regex would give an empty array in this case.

Comment: @DavidKnipe: I added `##alot` string to the list, it is working.

Comment: Ah,  of course, it works because it matches from just before the last `#`. And things like `%#alot` and `~#alot` will also match, which is possibly not what we wanted. We only want it to work if the previous character was a space. Hmmm... you could do `/\s#+([a-z]\w*)/gi`, and then `re.exec(' ' + str)`. Or else just `/(^|\s)#([a-z]\w*)/gi`

Comment: "We"? :) Well, `/(^|\s)#([a-z]\w*)/gi` is a possible solution in case there is such a requirement.

Comment: We're on the same side... aren't we? I don't think OP wants `%#alot` to match, but the question is slightly ambiguous in that it mentions a "string of words" but doesn't state how to split the string into words. Maybe one could argue that it doesn't matter because no one will ever write `%#alot` anyway.

Comment: @David Knight and stribizhev I had to slim down your solution to get it to work with the tests I am checking it against which is Test.assertEquals(getHashtags("Hello #world")[0], "world");
Test.assertEquals(getHashtags("#sorryNotSorry")[0], "sorryNotSorry");           as you can see we need to provide the strings without the hashtags, iismathwizards solution achieves this but fails when hashtags are in#line.

Comment: and also when it says "only the last hash counts" it means if you have ##alot we want you to return the word after the last hash -> alot.

Comment: @nexus404: My solution also returns the hashtags without `#`. It is `m[1]` variable. See my update.

Comment: Hi @stibizhev I had to slim down your solution again to get it to work on the website it expects an array back so I used this part of your solution: `function getHashtags(post){

var re = /\B#+([a-z]\w*)/gi; 
var arr = [];
while ((m = re.exec(post)) !== null) {
    arr.push(m[1]);
  
  console.log(arr) 
   
  }
 return arr; 
}`        now it is now stuck on string input:   #blue#red#yellow#green where it matches ['blue'] it is expecting an empty array as that long string has an inline hashtag

Comment: Then use `var re = /\B#+([a-z]\w*(?!#)\b)/gi;`